# Standard code running incredibly slow

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently coding a lengthy program in vba on Excel.  My code all seems to run fine until it gets to these three lines. The strange part is that this seems to be standard code and found it on the microsoft website, so I'm not sure why it would be working so terribly:

```
Worksheets("Product Structure").Range("L2:Q" & Last).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).Clear
Worksheets("Product Structure").Range("X2:AC" & Last).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).Clear
Worksheets("Product Structure").Range("F" & Last & ":K53000").Clear
```

When I run these excel freaks out and won't respond, many times ending up in me having to restart the program.  The variable "Last" is normally around 30,000 lines so obviously it is having to look through a lot of data.  Also, these two ranges of data are completely full with functions and these two lines are intended to delete the functions that didn't work.

Does anyone have a better solution? Thanks!

Comment: Excel is recalculating all of the formulas in the spreadsheet. This can definitely be costly.

Comment: Could you have some events firing?  Try `Application.EnableEvents = False` before clearing the cells.

Comment: You should also try setting the SpecialCells into a range variable, and clearing the contents of that variable.  This will tell us which part of the operation is the bottleneck.

Comment: Try identifying if any of the three lines is clearly and solely responsible for the sluggishness. To help with such task, try setting `Last` to low and high values prior to executing those lines, the first two would change speed in the opposite direction as the the last.

Comment: What version of Excel? There may be an issue here with handling more than 8192 areas with SpecialCells. Seeing a sample workbook would help.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off screenupdating before running the code. You could also try suspending Calculation by setting it to manual, but you should probably calculate the sheet between calls to Clear in case there are dependencies between the two areas where you're clearing cells.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

With Worksheets("Product Structure")

    .Range("L2:Q" & Last).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).Clear
    .UsedRange.Calculate 'if any dependencies
    .Range("X2:AC" & Last).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).Clear
    .Range("F" & Last & ":K53000").Clear

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: I run everything with Screen Updating off and manual calculation, and I manually calculate sheets/ranges as needed.  But thank you for the format, is using a "With" statement more efficient in your opinion? I will try this change.

Comment: Using `With` alone likely won't make any real difference to the execution: it only saves a few property lookups.

Comment: you could also try to switch off events, that sometimes help