# Excel VBA - very slow, and weird behaviour - Something else running?

Tags: excel, vba

ok - Excel VBA -

is running very slow, and weird behaviour - Is something else running?

- the text I'm typing sometimes gets all "rearranged" automatically (ie. first letter I type will be at the end all of a sudden)
- the text of the current line I'm on turns all red
- In the middle of typing something, a window will pop up "Syntax Error" even before I'm done typing.

I have turned off the addins (I have TM1 - which is a pain in the rear end)

I have optimised the code i am using, and have been coding for a long time and there is NOTHING that should be taking this long...

HELP!!!

```html
    Sub CreateCopy3()
    Dim x As Long
    Dim sumFilterNo As Long
    Dim m As Long
    Dim DelMe As Long
    Dim nCount As Long
    Dim lRowC_DoW
    Dim newSh As String
    Dim mp As Long
    Dim shDoW
    Dim shData As String
    Dim shCons As String
    Dim shXX As String
    Dim shDoWXX As String
    Dim sFilter As String
    Dim sFilterCol As String
    Dim sFilterColNumber As Long
    Dim shName As String
    Dim sFilterBy As String
    Dim lRowC As Long
    Dim lRowC_Sum As Long
    Dim lRowC_new As Long
    Dim niceName As String
    Dim l As Long
    Dim RptFilteredBy As String
    Dim lLastRow As Long, lLastColumn As Long
    Dim lRealLastRow As Long, lRealLastColumn As Long
    Dim arrAgent() As String
    Dim j As Long
    
    
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    shDoWXX = "DOW XX"
    shXX = "ZZ"
    shData = "Data"
    shCons = "Consolidated"
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    sFilter = Range("B2").Value
    sFilterBy = Range("B3").Value
    lRowC = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 11
    
    
    
    Select Case sFilter
        Case "AGENT_CODE"
            shName = "Agent"
            sFilterCol = "J"
            sumFilterNo = 1
            niceName = "Agent Code"
            sFilterColNumber = 1
        Case "ACCOUNT_MANAGER"
            sFilterCol = "F"
            shName = "AM"
            sumFilterNo = 5
            niceName = "Account Manager"
            sFilterColNumber = 30
        Case "Regional_Sales_Manager"
            sFilterCol = "G"
            sumFilterNo = 6
            shName = "SM"
            sFilterColNumber = 31
            niceName = "Reg. Sales Manager"
        Case "Customer"
            shName = "Customer"
            sFilterCol = "I"
            sumFilterNo = 9
            niceName = "Customer"
            sFilterColNumber = 33
        Case "Region"
            shName = "Region"
            sFilterCol = "C"
            sumFilterNo = 2
            niceName = "Region"
           sFilterColNumber = 29
        Case "Top_Level_Region"
            sumFilterNo = 1
            shName = "Top Region"
            sFilterCol = "B"
            niceName = "Top Level Region"
           sFilterColNumber = 28
        Case Else
            MsgBox "No Selection - operation cancelled"
            Exit Sub
    End Select
    
    RptFilteredBy = niceName & " filtered by " & Range("B3").Value
    Range("B9").Value = RptFilteredBy
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets(shData).Activate
    lRowC = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    
    
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    'Range("A13:Z" & lRowC).Clear
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then
    '    Range("A3:AZ3").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
    End If
    Range("A13:Z" & lRowC).Clear
    
    Worksheets(shCons).Activate
    
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False Then
        Range("A3:AZ3").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
    End If
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then
        Range("A3:AZ3").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
    End If
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False Then
        Range("A3:AZ3").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
    End If
    
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$AZ$" & lRowC).AutoFilter Field:=sFilterColNumber, Criteria1:= _
         sFilterBy, Operator:=xlAnd
    Range("G11").Select
    
    Range("A3").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    Range("A12").Activate
    Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA(R[12]C[-1]:R[" & lRowC & "]C[-1])"
    
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$13:$A$" & lRowC + 10 & "").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Range("B13").Select
    
    
    '**************** remove errors **********************
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then
        Range("A12:AZ12").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
    End If
    Application.StatusBar = "Calculations for summary page"
    lRowC_Sum = Range("B1").Value + 12
    If lRowC_Sum < 13 Then lRowC_Sum = 13
    
    Range("B13").Activate
    
    
    Range("B13:C" & lRowC & ",E13:M1" & lRowC & "").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=INDEX(Consolidated!R3C1:R" & lRowC & "C73,MATCH(RC1,Consolidated!C1,0),MATCH(R5C,Consolidated!R3C1:R3C53,0))"
    '
    
    Range("B13:Z" & lRowC).Value = Range("B13:Z" & lRowC).Value
    Range("D13:D" & lRowC).FormulaR1C1 = "=""VS""&LEFT(RC[-3],4)"
        Range("d13:d" & lRowC).Value = Range("d13:d" & lRowC).Value
    
    
        Range("O13:O" & lRowC).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(Consolidated!C1,RC1)"
        Range("Q13:Q" & lRowC).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(Consolidated!C1,RC1,Consolidated!C[-4])"
        Range("R13:R" & lRowC).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(Consolidated!C1,RC1,Consolidated!C[-4])"
        Range("P13:P" & lRowC).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[1]:RC[2])"
        Range("S13:S" & lRowC).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]/RC[-4]"
        Range("T13:T" & lRowC).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(Consolidated!C1,RC1,Consolidated!C[-4])"
        Range("U13:U" & lRowC).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(Consolidated!C1,RC1,Consolidated!C[-3])"
        Range("V13:V" & lRowC).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]/RC[-2]"
        Range("W13:W" & lRowC).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(Consolidated!C1,RC1,Consolidated!C[-6])"
        Range("X13:X" & lRowC).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(Consolidated!C1,RC1,Consolidated!C[-5])"
        Range("Y13:Y" & lRowC).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]/RC[-2]"
    
        Range("O10").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[3]C:R[" & lRowC_Sum & "]C)"
        Range("P10").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[3]C:R[" & lRowC_Sum & "]C)"
        Range("Q10").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[3]C:R[" & lRowC_Sum & "]C)"
        Range("R10").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[3]C:R[" & lRowC_Sum & "]C)"
        Range("S10").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-2]/RC[-4])"
        Range("T10").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[3]C:R[" & lRowC_Sum & "]C)"
        Range("U10").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[3]C:R[" & lRowC_Sum & "]C)"
        Range("V10").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-1]/RC[-2])"
        Range("W10").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[3]C:R[" & lRowC_Sum & "]C)"
        Range("X10").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[3]C:R[" & lRowC_Sum & "]C)"
        Range("Y10").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-1]/RC[-2])"
    
    Range("X13").Select
    
    Range("B13:DA" & lRowC_Sum).NumberFormat = "#,###;[Red](#,###)"
    Range("S13:S" & lRowC_Sum).Style = "Percent"
    Range("V13:V" & lRowC_Sum).Style = "Percent"
    Range("Y13:Y" & lRowC_Sum).Style = "Percent"
    Range("N13:N" & lRowC_Sum).NumberFormat = "0"
    Range("K13:K" & lRowC_Sum).NumberFormat = "0"
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA(R[12]C[1]:R[" & lRowC & "]C[1])"
    lRowC = Range("B1").Value
    
    
    Range("A12:AZ12").Select
    
    '**************** remove errors **********************
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False Then
        Range("A12:AZ12").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
    End If
     
     
         
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$AZ" & lRowC_Sum).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="#N/A"
    On Error GoTo 0
     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Range("A12").Select
    
    Do
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then Exit Do
    Loop Until ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then
        Selection.AutoFilter
    End If
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False Then
        Selection.AutoFilter
    End If
    
    
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$AZ$" & lRowC_Sum).AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="0"
    On Error GoTo 0
    Do
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then Exit Do
    Loop Until ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    
    Range("G2").Select
    
    
    '****************  errors removed **********************
    Application.StatusBar = "Formatting...."
    Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA(R[12]C[1]:R[" & lRowC & "]C[1])"
    lRowC = Range("B1").Value
    Application.StatusBar = ""
    
    MsgBox "Summary Reports Created for " & vbCrLf & niceName & " " & sFilterBy
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you update the post with your source code?

Comment: To get rid of the second and third problem you should disable "Auto syntax check" in `Tools->Options`. "Rearranging" of text happened to me only on laptops with too sensitive touchpad. Hard to judge why the code is running slow - no samples attached.

Comment: without code this is a pointless question

Comment: actually ALL code is running slowly, so therefore 'without code this is pointless' is incorrect, thank you however, for your valuable input

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you checked your **Excel Workbook** code? By that I mean there is no update code in your workbook not your VBA modules.
2. Have you tried turning off the **Excel recalc and display** while your code is running?

   ```
   Application.Calculation = xlManual
   ' Then later setting it back to Automatic, and

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   ' Do code and stop screen flickering
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   ```
3. Is a **rogue Excel** version open? Even if you restart your current instance -  I sometimes get errors when another Excel 32bit has been opened by another app when I am working in Excel 64bit. Look at Task manager.
4. Is the **sheet corrupted**? A last resort but have you tried opening another new workbook and copying your data and code into it, and resaving from fresh. I have used this to get past erratic behaviour especially with big sheets on a network.

Just trying to help you track down this irritating behaviour.

Comment: 1)  yes - have been coding for 15 yrs. so have an idea of what to look for.  minimal loops, etc

Comment: 2) yes, application.calc  & screen updating turned off

Comment: I thought you would have 2. covered. Sounds frustrating! Have you also tried disabling events? See @Qbik's [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27533476/standard-code-running-incredibly-slow?rq=1](comment in this answer)

Comment: just trying the code with the enable events = false, still slow (will update op in a mo)  weirdly i do have 2 versions open? or is this just excel having a moment - there should only be on *workbook* open

i cant add an image as dont have the rep yet, but task manager says
*workbook* and *microsoft excel - workbook*  does this mean a dodgy one is open or is this just how it shows it?

Comment: thansk micstr - apreciate your help  4: i tried that before, its one of my first 'go to' s when something unexplainable happens.  there are 8830 rows of data

Comment: "To get rid of the second and third problem you should disable "Auto syntax check" in Tools->Options"   but why is it firing? thats the issue

Comment: there are more variables declared than used, as i have cut off some code which was running after,

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily the answer, but perhaps it will give you another thing to look at. Two ideas:

1) I have had similar behavior while coding in Access. In my particular instance I had a hidden form running in the background that was linked to a timer. The timer triggered code that would check some tables in the DB.

The end result was very similar behavior to what you are describing. Code being cut off in the middle of the line while i was writing it. Code turning red. Etc.

Do you have any timers running in the background?

2) I have not had issues with TM1, but our EIKON Add-In causes all sorts of weirdbehavior, such as not returning shell commands. The only thing that helped in that instance as removing the Add-In entirely. Not just deactivating it. Removing it!